# Converting multidimensional object to array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a following object:

```
object(Intro\IntroBundle\Entity\User)#333 (6) {
      ["id":"Intro\IntroBundle\Entity\User":private]=>
      int(3)
      ["username":"Intro\IntroBundle\Entity\User":private]=>
      string(3) "aaa"
      ["email":"Intro\IntroBundle\Entity\User":private]=>
      string(9) "aa@aa.com"
      ["password":"Intro\IntroBundle\Entity\User":private]=>
      string(4) "a1a1"
      ["age":"Intro\IntroBundle\Entity\User":private]=>
      int(10)
      ["dateCreated":"Intro\IntroBundle\Entity\User":private]=>
      object(DateTime)#330 (3) {
        ["date"]=>
        string(26) "2011-01-01 01:01:00.000000"
        ["timezone_type"]=>
        int(3)
        ["timezone"]=>
        string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
      }
    }
```

I used methods:

```
array($entity);
json_decode(json_encode($entity), true);
get_object_vars ($entity);
```

and with a personal method

```
private function objToArray($obj){
    $arr = array();
    if(!is_object($obj) && !is_array($obj)){
        $arr = $obj;
        die("invalid data");
    }

    foreach ($obj as $key => $value)
    {
        if (!empty($value))
        {
            $arr[$key] = array();
            objToArray($value, $arr[$key]);
        }
        else
        {
            $arr[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

All those methods return an empty array. Please tell me why? I mention that my object input (`$entity`) is not empty.
And also please don't give me dislike if you do not know the answer.

Comment: this is because all variable or members are private in mentioned object

Comment: I don't think my object is private because I can display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object's properties are private. If you `var_dump()` an object as you did it prints also `private` properties.

Have a look at this article http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php. You can iterate object as you do but it iterates only public properties.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we can't see the scope. All your code is private (object properties and the method). Show the scope and we can help you better.

The problem seems to be here:

```
   if (!empty($value))
   {
       $arr[$key] = array();
       objToArray($value, $arr[$key]);
   }
```

You are passing a second argument that doesn't defined in the method

```
 private function objToArray($obj){...}
```

So you are passing a value to `objToArray()`, that value is a string I guess, and when it reach this line:

```
   $arr = array();

if(!is_object($obj) && !is_array($obj)){
     $arr = $obj;
     die("invalid data");
}
```

Then it will display "invalid data", and empty your array.